# Temporary url for physical files in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am going to add some kind of security in my site . So i was thinking that is this possible to have temporary url to physical files .

Suppose i have a javascript file which is needed by my login page in order to run correctly . So can i do this something like dynamic suppose we have a url which is valid for current session of user when user logout that url gets expired .

The main purpose is that i don't want to disclose real path to my file

Comment: Why are you trying to hide javascript files from a user?  In what ways will that increase security on your site?

Comment: well i think its good i donot disclose real url for javascript and css files , but may be i am wrong . Please correct me if i am

Comment: There is nothing wrong with disclosing the "real location" for content files.  I cannot think of any sites or reasons to obfuscate that path.  For security, worry more about things like cross site scripting vulnerabilities, ensure you are using the anti-forgery token on form POSTs and if you are not using an ORM like EntityFramework, then ensure that all SQL queries are using parameterized inputs.  These are the big worries for a web application.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of a virtual path is to hide the real path from the browser. You can make a virtual path that is different from the physical path and the outside world will have no concept of where your actual file is.

You can map a virtual directory to any directory on your file system so it has a virtual path. Let's say you want to make the physical directory `C:\temp\Images\` into a virtual directory called `/Images/` and you are using IIS 7.

1. Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
2. Under sites, navigate to the site you wish to place the virtual directory in.
3. Right click on the site node, and click "Add Virtual Directory...".
4. For the alias, type `Images`.
5. For the Physical Path, type `C:\temp\Images\`.
6. Click OK.

Now you can access your image through the virtual directory `/Images/img1.jpg`. The browser has no idea that it is in the physical directory `C:\temp\Images\`.

There is an issue with what you are proposing. If you did host your JavaScript file on a "temporary URL for the current session", it means that the browser would not be able to cache the file and performance would not be optimal.

I cannot see any advantage to what you are proposing because regardless of what you do, the browser (and thus the user) will have access to your JavaScript code. The only difference is you will have a lot of complex code to generate temporary URLs that seem to serve no purpose.

Comment: Nice explanation , now i got . Good point that eventually user will have access to our javascript code . But what if we minify our javascript files

Comment: Minification can *obfuscate* the code, but it can still be reverse engineered with a little patience. The bottom line is that you should never store anything you want to keep secure in a JavaScript file - consider it to be publicly accessible code. But *do* minify your JavaScript files because it helps your website perform better.